# Vue axios cross origin error to regular web URL

Tags: vue.js, cors

I have a Vue app with which I want to pull in data from a shared Airtable page (public url without a password). Unfortunately I keep getting a CORS error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://airtable.com/shrMc78Hss0Oyfz2J' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

In the example code below I'm using axios. I have tried using request promise as well as fetch but same issue appears. I have tried different domains to make sure this wasn't Airtable specific but the same issue keeps coming up. It happens on development as well as on production.

I don't know how to set up CORS on Vue and I haven't been able to find any useful documentation on this online. Maybe I'm missing something...

This is the Vue component:

```
<template>
  <div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  mounted: function () {
    this.getAT();
  },
  methods: {
    getAT: function () {
    axios.get('https://airtable.com/shrMc78Hss0Oyfz2J', { crossdomain: true })
    .then((res) => {
        console.log(res)
      })
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

EDIT:
In contrast to many other questions on the same topic, I'm not trying to connect to my own backend. Instead, I am trying to scrape a page. This means I don't have access to that page to change the cors settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CORS is actually the problem between the backend and the browser. It's not Vue blocked your requests, but your browser. By default, browsers restrict cross-origin requests like this.
Read more about CORS at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

To bypass CORS, you should modify the backend to accept requests from your frontend origin, or use a proxy server to send requests on behalf of you.

Comment: In this case I'm not trying to connect to my backend, but to an external url. The goal is to scrape it, so I don't have the possibility to change it.

Comment: Then you should go for a proxy server. There are some out there already, such as corsanywhere. Or you can write your own api on your backend to call to that external url, then on the frontend side, just call that backend api you wrote, that works as well.